# SQL Server transactions and concurrency

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, transactions

Could someone please explain me this line of code? I was trying to cut it into smaller pieces, but it doesn't ring any bell for me. Thank you.

```
 SqlTransaction transaction = cn.BeginTransaction(System.Data.IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted);
```

Left side is pretty obvious, then on the right side we call begin transaction method on the connection variable, but the stuff in the () is not quite clear. Thank you.

Comment: Have you looked at the class documentation on MSDN? What wasn't clear? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ha4240h(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code snippet starts a new transaction with a Read Committed transaction isolation level. Isolation levels are a trait of transactions indicating how isolated the transaction is from the data modifications made by other simultaneous transactions.

See [MSDN IsolationLevel Enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.isolationlevel(v=vs.110).aspx) for more info on the `System.Data.IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted` isolation level used in your example and for alternatives.

See [MSDN Understanding Isolation Levels](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378149(v=sql.110).aspx) for more on isolation levels.

Answer (score 0):

This line is equal to

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED
GO
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
...--some code here
```

in SQL.

[Isolation levels with explanations @ msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173763.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

With this line in C# is equal to:

```
BEGIN TRAN 
TRY
   DELETE FROM TABLENAME ecc ecc
   COMMIT
CATCH
   ROLLBACK
```

Isolation level used in your example and for alternatives.